# Count remaining items in order to calculate percentages

Tags: jquery

I have a page where a user has to drag items from an area elsewhere on a screen.

When all items are dragged out -- 100% task is accomplished.

I would like to calculate what % of the task is accomplished on each drag and drop (when an items is dragged out of gray area).

How do I count remaining items within an area?

How do I convert into percentages?

Shall I calculate what each item's worth in terms of % on page load and then subtract?

Comment: "Sorry, it appears that you already participated in this usability test." - So much for going back to evaluate the code...

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Tested something and left accidentally. Pls try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on Chris May's comment, try this :

```
var startCount = $("#launchPad .card").length;

$(".stack").bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
    var currentCount = startCount - $("#launchPad .card").length + 1;
    alert(currentCount / startCount * 100 + "%");
});
```

Here it starts since the first drop from 0% to 100%

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/qQdZy/

EDIT :
This should fix the problem :)

```
var startCount = $("#launchPad .card").length;

$(".stack").bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
    var currentCount = startCount - $("#launchPad .card").length;
    if (currentCount != startCount)
        currentCount++;
    alert(currentCount / startCount * 100 + "%");
});
```

New fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qQdZy/1/

**NEW EDIT** :
Ok, I have changed my solution. Here it works :

```
var startCount = $("#launchPad .card").length;
var moveFromLaunch = false;

$(".card").bind( "dragstart", function(event, ui) {
  moveFromLaunch = true;
});

$(".stack").bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
    var currentCount = $("#launchPad .card").length;
    if (moveFromLaunch)
        currentCount--;
    currentCount = startCount - currentCount;
    moveFromLaunch = false;
    alert(currentCount / startCount * 100 + "%");
});
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/qQdZy/3/

Comment: This is great! I think you got it.

Comment: Just noticed something... After I reach 100% and then drag an item from one box to another I get 100% + 1 increment. I need to cap it at 100% as soon as it reaches it. How do i do that?

Comment: Sorry, just tested again. The fix only helps if someone moves an item from box to box at the end. If that happens at the beginning, the count still increments.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for helping me out with this.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var startCount = $('#launchPad .card').length,


    $("#dropZone").bind( "drop", function(event, ui) {
        var currentCount = $('#launchPad .card').length;
        alert(currentCount/startCount);
    });

});
```

Comment: The drop event fires for Droppables (the "boxes"), not Draggables (the "cards").

Comment: Cool! In PHP I can doo either floor or ceil to round-up results, can something like this be done in jQuery? I don't want to have to deal with decimals...

Comment: @santa, you can use the same functions, pretty much, in JavaScript: [`Math.floor(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) and [`Math.ceil(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil) where `x` is the number, or variable name, to be worked on. Please note the upper-case `M` on `Math`.

Comment: When I do initial drop it still calculates 100% remaining. If I move an item from box to box -- it calculates correctly... A bit confused how to implement this to work properly.

Comment: Looks like the `currentCount` should be `var currentCount = startCount - $('#launchPad .card').length;`. Otherwise, you start at 100% and each drag would bring the completed percentage down. And if you're getting a 100% remaining on the initial drop, the calculation is happening before the DOM updates.